# How to add a custom jPanel to jFrame multiple times?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I have made `JPanel` class with one `JComboBox` and two `JTextField` controls.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JPanel p = new JPanel();
ComparisonPanel cp = new ComparisonPanel(); //jPanel with a few elements
ComparisonPanel cp2 = new ComparisonPanel();

p.setLayout(new FlowLayout()/*new GridLayout(2, 2)*/);

f.getContentPane().add(cp);
f.getContentPane().add(cp2/*cp*/);
f.setVisible(true);
```

It shows the `ComparisonPanel` only once. I am actually trying to generate a GUI on runtime, the panel will be repeated with a few modifications (different labels etc) and then get the values from this dynamically generated GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting `p`'s layout but not the layout of the container you're trying to add your JPanel to, the contentPane, a container that uses BorderLayout by default. BorderLayout-using containers will only all the last component added (in a default way) to be shown, and that is messing you up.

Suggestion: add your ComparsonPanel objects to the p JPanel, then add **that** single component to the contentPane. i.e.,

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JPanel p = new JPanel();
ComparisonPanel cp = new ComparisonPanel(); //jPanel with a few elements
ComparisonPanel cp2 = new ComparisonPanel();

p.setLayout(new FlowLayout()/*new GridLayout(2, 2)*/);

p.add(cp);
p. add(cp2);
f.getContentPane().add(p);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
```

Better yet, read the [layout manager tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Comment: Thank you that worked fine. I am new to java (worked with c#). I will be adding a button in the end to get values from all the fields that I have added. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @LifeH2O: read the layout manager tutorial and try to play with layout managers to achieve the best GUI possible. Note that it's often best to nest JPanels each using its own layout manager. Then try to work on your program, one step and one problem at a time til solved.

Comment: I am reading tutorials but user interface is not real problem in my case. I need to get the values he selected on each jPanel I added.